# How to get LibreOffice Calc to recognize dates in YYYY/MM/DD format?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, format, date

I've been given a large tab-separated-values (TSV) text file that contains dates in the format YYYY/MM/DD.

I tried copy and pasting the dates into LibreOffice Calc, but it didn't recognize the strings as dates.

Is there a way to get LibreOffice Calc to recognize dates in that format?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying and pasting, open the TSV file in Calc. In the "Text Import" dialog that appears:

1. Click the header of the column of dates shown in the **Fields** section,
2. Select `Date (YMD)` from the "Column type:" drop-down list, and
3. Click `OK`.

The file should be imported with the data in that column imported as dates and displayed in Calc's current default date format — MM/DD/YY in my case. You can then select the column and format it to the date format of your choice.

If your intent is to add the data to an existing spreadsheet, import as noted above, and then copy & paste the dates from the imported file spreadsheet to the existing spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you David!  Upvoted. I will give that a try.